# Accessing phone features such as camera and phone using jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Is it possible to access mobile features such as camera,sensors etc from a html page that is designed using jquery mobile.

In other words is it possible to use mobile features using jquery mobile?

That make it obvious that I will be viewing the page in mobile phone.

Comment: Jquery only has access to what the browser can access, which varies between browsers.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery Mobile has an [orientationchange event](http://api.jquerymobile.com/orientationchange/) that fires when a mobile device switches between a vertical or horizontal orientation.

jQuery Mobile does not have methods for accessing the camera, gyroscopes or other sensors.

There are some upcoming standards that will allow you to access the camera and other sensors but support for them in mobile browsers will not be widespread for quite some time. The mobile versions of Firefox and Chrome, and possibly mobile Safari, should have decent support for most of these APIs but most other mobile browsers probably won't.

Some resources:

- [Capturing Audio & Video in HTML5](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/)
- [This End Up: Using Device Orientation](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/device/orientation/)
- [Using geolocation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation)
- [Using Web Notifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/Using_Web_Notifications)